# failing to load the angular module textangular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

after following the instructions here

https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/

1) added the script tag with textagnular js file.

2)In my app definition which was

```
var myApp_ = angular.module('myApp', [ 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngResource']);
```

I changed it to

```
var myApp_ = angular.module('myApp', [ 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngResource' , 'textAngular']);
```

I get 
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] > Failed to instantiate module textAngular.
This error occurs when a module fails to load due to some exception.

What else am I missing?

Comment: Didn't forget to include textAngular.js in your index.html? After angular.js and before your applicaiton code?

Comment: no...I have the script tag including it

Comment: Could you show your index.html, then?

Answer (score 1):

It has some additional [requirements](https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/#requirements). angular sanitize module, which is separate file.

You may download it from [here](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-sanitize.js)

Comment: To add a correction, it's recomended you use the included textAngular-sanitize over angular-sanitize. They're essentially the same except the textAngular one allows some specific style attributes through.

Comment: @SimeonCheeseman I have included "textAngular-sanitize.min.js" and dependency "ngSanitize" to my app module. but still when I add inline styles to the content of textAngular, it gets stripped off. I am using latest version 1.3.7. Please let me know if I am missing something!!!

Comment: You don't need to add the "ngSanitize" dependancy to your app (It's a dependancy of textAngular). If you didn't have that before I'd guess that somewhere you are also loading up "angular-sanitize" as well as "textAngular-Sanitize".  Also "textAngular-Sanitize" only supports a small number of inline styles. Primarily color, background-color, text-align, float, width, height and direction. Ref: https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/blob/master/src/textAngular-sanitize.js#L508-L535

Answer (score 1):

Include (textAngularSetup.js along with textAngular.js) or just textAngular.min.js 
(textAngularSetup.js is included inside textAngular.min.js)

Check https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/#requirements

Comment: Also, latest version from 1.5.x forces you to use their sanitize than angular's.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the minified version of textAngular that already links to it's sanitation module and you don't need to include a extra link (at least for the version I got via the bower packet manager).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you include de textAngular-xxx.js below the include of angular.js in your html.